# Notifications are working on an emulator but not on a real device

Tags: android, android-notifications

im trying to test my app on a Samsung Galaxy S7(Android 8.0), but the notifications do not appear, i have checked app permissions and battery settings, what ele it could be?

```
public void sendNotification(View view)
{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //creating the intent that’ll fire when the user taps the notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //making notification disappear after being clicked
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("TI connect");
    mBuilder.setContentText("New report has been added!  Total reports: " + repNo);
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: You need to use the new `Builder` of `NotificationCompat` when your api is more than `26.1.0`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#notificationcompatbuilder

Comment: Are both emulator and real device OS versions same?

Comment: no, im using 21level API on my emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Android 8.0 required **Channal**

you need to add this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
```

and

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
notificationBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
```

Comment: @surani, i am having a similar problem, where do i add you code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your problem

```
 private void ShowNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle("Test Message")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

and in `strings.xml`

```
 <string name="default_notification_channel_id">1</string>
```